# Git Server Mirroring

Tags: git, github

How do you set up a git server to PULL from another git server?  I have a post-update hook that pushes to github as an offsite backup, but I also want it to PULL from github.  How can I accomplish this?

EDIT:

Let me rephrase a little.  What I am hoping to accomplish is have 2 seperate remotes that mirror one another, one on my company's WAN and another on github.  I already have a post-update hook that pushes all updates from the WAN to github, but I need this to work both ways.  Thanks for the help

Comment: Unattended merges are dangerous I'd suggest you make the remote devs commit to a different branch on github and then fetch&merge them manually on to the repo hosted on company WAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the general case, you can't; pulling potentially requires a merge, and you can't merge without a working tree, which your server presumably doesn't have.  (And even if it did...  an unattended merge is a bad idea.)

If you want to outright overwrite a branch, you can just fetch it with `git fetch github master:master`.  But it sounds like you expect both repositories to see new commits?  If GitHub is only acting as a backup here, why would you need to pull from it?

Comment: Github is also functioning as the remote for remote devs.  All onsite devs point to a local repo for performance and bandwidth sake, and all remote devs point to github for the same reason.

Comment: you're causing yourself a huge hassle there.  the whole point of having a canonical repository is to have a singular reference for the current state of the code.  you should just pick one to use and be done with it; the bandwidth cost of shuttling gzipped text around is far less than the headache of keeping two heavily-active repositories synchronized.

Comment: I understand, I am still learning.  The in-house repo is accessible from the outside, but we get frequent disconnects when attempting to clone large repos.  Any ideas there?

Comment: Use the github backup just for the cloning and let remote people push to the in-house repo directly. Trust is the key here though.

Comment: you could encourage them to use the read-only github url (`git://...`) for cloning, which would prevent them from accidentally pushing to github.  or, heck, just don't allow employees to push to github.